# Ajax Success Function and Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, variables, global-variables

I'm using AJAX to get a current post data for 'Store'.  And I'm using AJAX to call the data for all stores, so that I can run a distance check with turf.js to show the 3 closest nearby stores to the current post/Store.  But of course, I can't access the arrays of store or stores outside of the success function due to variable scope being restricted to just the success function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
let cur_store_id = $('#map').attr('data-store-id');

// Get Current Store Data
$.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/champlainfarms/champlain-farms/wp-json/champlain/v1/store/' + cur_store_id,

} ).success( function( data ) {
     store = data;
} );

// Get all Store to calculate nearest Stores
$.ajax( {
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/champlainfarms/champlain-farms/wp-json/champlain/v1/stores/`,

} ).success( function( data ) {
    stores = data;
    console.log('Pulled All Stores');
 )};

   // Returns variable not specified as scope doesn't allow variable out
   if (stores.length > 0 ) {
        console.log ("There is more than 20 locations in Stores");
    }

)};
```

How do can I pass the store or stores variable outside of the AJAX `.success()` ?  I understand AJAX is asynchronous, so how do I wait till the data is returned and then work with with it outside of the `.success()` ?

Comment: "Asynchronous" means that nothing waits. You have to do your work in the callback, or via Promises, or `async`/`await`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to work with it outside of `.success()`? You said you need to wait until the data is returned, and that is exactly what `.success()` is for. So, you could do this:

```
.success( function( data ) {
    stores = data;
    console.log('Pulled All Stores');
    if (stores.length > 0 ) {
        console.log ("There is more than 20 locations in Stores");
    }
})
```

If you still want to be able to access the `stores` variable outside of `.success()`, you could declare it with some default empty value before the AJAX call.